# Flush cache on per user basis

Tags: caching, asp.net-web-api

I'm using https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache to add easy caching to my web-api project and I have an action that look something like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 86400, ServerTimeSpan = 86400)]
    public List<Things> GetThings()
    {
        return service.GetThings();
    }
```

Now *things* are a combination of a list of *things* that apply to everybody along with user-defined *things* that are created by a user and accessible only to that user. So I want the cache here to be tied to a specific user. I don't want user `Bob` getting a list of things that included things that are specific to `Sally`. So I created my own key generator, inheriting from `DefaultCacheKeyGenerator` that will append the user id:

```
    public override string MakeCacheKey(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext context, System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType, bool excludeQueryString = false)
    {
        var key = base.MakeCacheKey(context, mediaType, excludeQueryString);
        return string.Format("{0}:{1}", key, userService.CurrentUser.UserID);
    }
```

The `UserID` here is ultimately pulled from the user authorization cookie.

This seems to work fine.

However, I have another action that will let the user save their custom *thing* and obviously when I POST here I want to invalidate the cache, so it looks something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [InvalidateCacheOutput("GetThings")]
    public void SaveUserThing(UserThingModel thing)
    {
        service.Save(thing);
    }
```

The *problem* (or rather the inefficiency) here is that from my understanding this will flush everything under this control and `GetThings` (the base key for all caches) which will include the cache for *every user*. This means if `Bob` saves a new thing, I'm going to force `Sally` to have to get a whole new list of things, even though her list won't have changed.

Is there an easy way around this? I suspect the problem lies in [CacheOutputConfiguration.MakeBaseCacheKey](https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache/blob/master/src/WebAPI.OutputCache/CacheOutputConfiguration.cs), but there doesn't seem to be a mechanism to override that functionality to have it build a base key from controller, action *and* userId.

I could probably just grab the source from GitHub and adapt to suit my needs, but I wanted to be sure I wasn't a) missing something obvious and b) barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: That's something I need too. Have you found a way to fix this? thank you

Comment: @Marc: Sadly not yet. It's on my TODO list at the moment. I posted it as an issue on [github](https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache/issues/79)

Comment: Have you found an answer to this yet? It's something I need to do too

Comment: Any news if you fixed this?